# Java SWT List item with long text

Tags: java, list, user-interface, text, swt

Im writing UI in Java, using SWT. I use in some places SWT `List`. 
But when I have items in the list that their length is more than the list default width, I cannot see their whole text. not with End button in the keyboard, and not with anything else.

Here is the code that generates the List:

```
List lstInputs = new List( shell, SWT.V_SCROLL );
```

any idea?

Comment: Did you try not setting the default width? Don't set the default width then the control automatically resizes.

Comment: If you need the List to scroll horizontally, you'll have to add the appropriate style flag (`new List( shell, SWT.V_SCROLL | SWT.H_SCROLL );`

Comment: The keys to move through the text may vary depending on which platform you are using (Mac, Linux, Windows...). The arrow keys may work.

Comment: thanks, but: Kode - I don't want the list to be wide, but I need to be able to see all of the content! @Rüdiger Herrmann -  I tried SWT.H_SCROLL and it didn't work. and greg-449 - I'm on Windows, and End key doesn't work. any other idea please?

Comment: @user1835297 I am running Windows 7 and `SWT.H_SCROLL` works just fine. What version of Windows/SWT arae you using?